# Evil mode motion: between blocks of text

Tags: evil, motion

**Block motion**

I would like to quickly swape through files and `j` `k` and `/` aren't cutting it anymore.

Is there a command to move between blocks of text?

**For example:**

What I mean by block movement,

- Initial state:
  [image]
- After issuing the command:
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `] ]` to go forward a section and `[ [` to go back one.

You can also use `C-f` and `C-b` to scroll up and down pages.
I've found using marks to be helpful, you set them with `m` and go to them with `'` or `] '`. Those might be worth looking into.

Comment: Wow, how was I living without these? Thank you.